# Why is Digest::SHA1 preventing proper annotation of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sha1, railstutorial.org, ruby-2.0, annotate

I am using [annotate](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) in my app and all models are successfully annotated except for user.rb, which shows the following error when I annotate:

> Unable to annotate user.rb: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Outside of annotating, everything else works fine. User creation, updating, deletion, login, sign out, it all works properly. I have determined that the problem is with the Digest::SHA1, which I use to create session tokens, as demonstrated below in the snippet from user.rb.

```
def User.new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.hash(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

  def create_remember_token
    remember_token = User.hash(User.new_remember_token)
  end
```

If I remove the second (def User.hash(token)) and instead do the following:

```
def User.new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

private
  def create_remember_token
    remember_token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(User.new_remember_token.to_s)
  end
```

then annotate is happy and successfully annotates user.rb. However, this isn't really the ruby way as my session helper utilizes that User.hash(token) call several times. What am I not understanding about Digest::SHA1.hexdigest or the way that I am utilizing it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're working through [The Rails Tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/).

The likely reason you're seeing issues with your `User.hash` method is nothing to do with `Digest::SHA1`, but is because the method itself is inadvertently overriding Ruby's [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-hash) method, which is giving you some cryptic errors.  [Link to Github issue about it](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/issues/29).

So, like [this commit to the Sample App repository](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/commit/07bae25cf7880b0355bbe73b8853f1a8e349ca7d), rename all your instances of `User.hash` to `User.digest` and hopefully that should fix your errors.